# Create a webhook using API in shopify

Tags: shopify, webhooks

Here I stuck in shopify creating webhook through API

I am using cake php for creating public shopify app

Now I would like to create carts/update hook for my app using API here is my code 
Cake php library : https://github.com/cmcdonaldca/CakePHP-Shopify-Plugin

**File :** ShopifyApiComponent.php

CODE :

```
public function createwebhook($shop_domain, $access_token){

    $method = "POST";
    $path = "/admin/webhooks.json";

    $params = array("webhook" => array( "topic"=>"carts/create",
                    "address"=>  $this->site_url."users/upUpdateCart",
                    "format"=> "json"));


    $password = md5($this->secret.$access_token);//If your shopify app is public
    $baseurl = "https://".$this->api_key.":".$password."@".$shop_domain."/";

    $url = $baseurl.ltrim($path, '/');
    $query = in_array($method, array('GET','DELETE')) ? $params : array();
    $payload = in_array($method, array('POST','PUT')) ? stripslashes(json_encode($params)) : array();
    $request_headers = in_array($method, array('POST','PUT')) ? array("Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8", 'Expect:') : array();
    $request_headers[] = 'X-Shopify-Access-Token: ' . $access_token;
                list($response_body, $response_headers) = $this->Curl->HttpRequest($method, $url, $query, $payload, $request_headers);


    $this->last_response_headers = $response_headers;
    $response = json_decode($response_body, true);

    if (isset($response['errors']) or ($this->last_response_headers['http_status_code'] >= 400))
        $body = $response['errors'];
    else
        $body = $response_body;
    /*Debug the output in a text_file*/
    $destination = realpath('../../app/webroot/execution_log') . '/';
    $fh = fopen($destination."shopify_app.txt",'a') or die("can't open file");
    date_default_timezone_set('GMT');

    fwrite($fh, "\n\nDATE: ".date("Y-m-d H:i:s")."\n".$body);
    fclose($fh);
    /*Debug Code Ends*/
    return (is_array($response) and (count($response) > 0)) ? array_shift($response) : $response;
}
```

and I called this function when I visit my app dashboard mean 
Controller : Offers
function :dashboard

But its not seems to work because when I visit 
https://test.myshopify.com/admin/webhooks.json its showing nothing but 
If I am creating webhook through Admin->Setting->Notification then it show listing here https://test.myshopify.com/admin/webhooks.json

Please let me know how we can create webhook using API (cake php )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shopify shows the list of webhooks through webhooks.json, those are created manually from the shopify admin. If you want to get the list of webhooks created through api then you need to run it from another browser or from a private browser (where shopify admin is not loged in)

Your link will be something like this - 
https://api-key:api-password@shop-name.myshopify.com/admin/webhooks.json

Note: replace api key and password of your app and replace shop name in the link and try it in a new/private browser window.

Comment: is there a way we can add sone script on thanku page after order placed

Comment: I don't think you will be able to customize anything in the think page.(through coding) because thank you page belongs to checkout.shopify.com domain and shopify does not allow to modify anything there. But its my thought..there might be a way.