# How to create a Custom Web hook in Shopify

Tags: shopify, shopify-app

I want to create a custom webhook in Shopify for Customer Login using a private app below is my code, but I'm getting the error  **Array ( [errors] => Array ( [topic] => Array ( [0] => Invalid topic specified. Topics allowed: app/uninstalled, carts/create, carts/update, checkouts/create, checkouts/delete, checkouts/update, checkouts/paid, collections/create, collections/delete, collections/update, customer_groups/create, customer_groups/delete, customer_groups/update, customers/create, customers/delete, customers/disable, customers/enable, customers/update, order_transactions/create, orders/cancelled, orders/create, orders/delete, orders/edited, orders/fulfilled, orders/paid, orders/partially_fulfilled, orders/updated, products/create, products/delete, products/update, refunds/create, shop/update, themes/create, themes/delete, themes/publish, themes/update, tender_transactions/create, app_purchases_one_time/update, app_subscriptions/update, variants/delete ) )**

```
session_start();

require __DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php';
use phpish\shopify;

require __DIR__.'/conf.php';

$shopify = shopify\client(SHOPIFY_SHOP, SHOPIFY_APP_API_KEY, SHOPIFY_APP_PASSWORD, true);

try
{
    # Making an API request can throw an exception



    $customers = $shopify('POST /admin/api/2020-01/webhooks.json', array(), array
    (
        'webhook' => array 
        (
            "topic" =>  "customers/login",
            "address" => "myappurl", 
            "format" => "json"
        )

    ));

    print_r($customers);
}
catch (shopify\ApiException $e)
{
    # HTTP status code was >= 400 or response contained the key 'errors'
    echo $e;
    print_R($e->getRequest());
    print_R($e->getResponse());
}
catch (shopify\CurlException $e)
{
    # cURL error
    echo $e;
    print_R($e->getRequest());
    print_R($e->getResponse());
}
```

Please help it is possible to create it from the private app or not?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Create a webhook using API in shopify](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44495615/create-a-webhook-using-api-in-shopify)

Comment: array ( 'topic' => array ( 0 => 'Invalid topic specified. Topics allowed: app/uninstalled,

Comment: getting same error

Comment: These is no such a topic like customers/login, 

these are valid topics for customer =>  customers/create, customers/disable, customers/enable, customers/update 

for more detail visit https://shopify.dev/docs/admin-api/rest/reference/events/webhook

Comment: @BhargavKaklotara What does the customer/update hook entail?
I am trying to listen to the customer tag change event. Is that possible?

Comment: Yes!  on the customers/update webhook you will get all the data, https://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/31347170?key=f8f25a7b2d933286f9f04b5bef661ee7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the use of web-hook you can get data on certain event occurred on shopify store which is provided by shopify itself.

to start listening this update you need to create webhook on particular store.

But you need to chose topic from the list provided by shopify.

Shopify do not provide webhook for Customer/Login event ( or topic ).

If you want to make update your system upon login you need to create custom notification ( fully custom solution ).

for that you can do is that...

Create custom code with JS & Liquid that make update to your system when user login.

you can do this via app using [App Proxy](https://shopify.dev/tutorials/display-data-on-an-online-store-with-an-application-proxy-app-extension)